# How do I write text to the username/password input controls of a 3rd party page using ASP.NET?

Tags: .net, asp.net

My title is pretty much the question: *"How do I write text to the username/password input controls of a 3rd party web page using ASP.NET?"*

Just for examples sake, if I wanted to write an ASP.NET page that would initially authenticate  a user on my end, and then redirect to a 3rd party site and log into it using the fields displayed with credentials my app has within it (encypted obviously), how can I do this?

If you had ever seen the old Microsoft FingerPrint reader USB control, it used to do this. The software would allow you to highlight fields on a web page, and then store the credentials you provide it, and auto write to the fields upon visiting the site and using your fingerprint. I don't want the finger print reader, just the similar functionality.

It will be a static 3rd party site and does *not* have to account for any site visited. I should be able to look at the source of the site I need to log into to if this helps.

Anyone know how to go about this? Thanks!!

Comment: Don't get caught up on my explination about pre-authenticating a user. I should have omitted that from the original description. It is unimportant to the question. In a nutshell, how can I write text to fields on a web page that is not mine?

Comment: this comment completely changes the meaning of this question, I would open a new SO question where you specifically ask what you stated in this comment. And explain you want a .NET windows application to write into fields of a web browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to use the `WebRequest` class and simulate a user controlling a web browser and manually execute each GET and POST operation that is required to log into the site.

Comment: Can you expand on this a bit, or do you have any links to examples? I have not done this before and need a bit more detail please.

Comment: Here is a good example of what I needed to do (it is not perfect though and does not work well for sites with JavaScript or AJAX): http://bit.ly/9atnGI

Answer (score 1):

You want to control the user's browser on a 3rd party site on a different domain.  This is not possible due to browser security restrictions.  You could try to open an IFRAME to a 3rd party site from your webpage, but you won't be able to do anything on the user's behalf.

See [MSDN: Cross Frame Scripting Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533028%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I would say this as well, unless the sites you are attempting to login to have an api for authentication, like Open ID.

Comment: OK how did the Microsoft fingerprint USB device work? All it did was take stored encrypted credentials and auto wrote them to the page's text boxes and pressed whatever button assigned (OK, Submit, Login, etc.). It had no relation to the site at all, you could do it on any site (banking, airline, hotels, social networking, whatever): http://www.microsoft.com/canada/hardware/mouseandkeyboard/features/fingerprint.mspx    Don't get caught up on my explination about pre-authenticating a user. I should have omitted that from the original description. It is unimportant to the question.